# Java webview specific link

Tags: java, android

I Have java application using web view the app load links from assets folder in this assets folder index page have more than links

```
for example these links are
https://google.com
https://stackoverflow.com
https://youtube.com
..etc
```

I Just need to display button with id (@+id/button) when user click on any link start with stack over flow
for example user click on one off these links

```
https://example.com/post/70253485/
https://example.com/post/89655365/
https://example.com/post/82683422/
....more links like this
```

java

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

activity_main

Comment: So you want to load an HTML file into a webview or actual websites?

Comment: on html page links go to actual websites but i need to show button inside the app when user click to link start with example.com but if the user click on link start with anther url don't show the button

Comment: You can add `<button>` tags inside the HTML. Otherwise, you need to write a bit more code to detect when then WebView navigates away/to any certain page; you won't be able to capture HTML link click events